# JPA Exception- Can not find constructor for <Class> with argument types "[class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]" to fill data

Tags: jpa, openjpa

**I use jBoss Fuse 6.1.0 with blueprint DSL with openJPA. I use Container Managed transaction (JTA) and transaction managed by Aspects that handles Commit and Rollback as of now**

I have following Classes that are JPA entities.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CLIENT")
@NamedQuery(name="Client.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Client c")
public class Client implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //Had to add this for avoiding exception. And it works as expected
    //Dummy constructor for JPA - Workaround
    public Client(String s1, String s2){}

    @Column(name="requestid", unique=true,nullable=false)
    private String requestId;

    @Id
    @Column(name="clientid", unique=true, nullable=false, length=128)
    private String clientId;


    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="REQUESTID", nullable=false)
    private RoccoRequest roccoRequest;

    //bi-directional One-To-Many association to ClientGroup
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="client",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ClientGroup> clientGroups;
....
,...
...
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Embeddable
@Table(name="CLIENTGROUP")
@NamedQuery(name="ClientGroup.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM ClientGroup c")
public class ClientGroup implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClientGroupPK id;

    @Column(length=32)
    private String type;

    @Column(name="clientid", length=128)
    private String clientId;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Client
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapsId("clientid")
    @JoinColumn(name="CLIENTID", nullable=true, insertable=false,  updatable=false)
    private Client client;
..
.
.
.
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ROCCOREQUEST")
@NamedQuery(name="RoccoRequest.CHECK_EXISISTING_CLIENT_DETAILS",
            query="SELECT r FROM RoccoRequest r JOIN r.client c WHERE c.crmId = :crmId")
public class RoccoRequest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="requestid", unique=true, nullable=false, length=128)
    private String requestId;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="roccoRequest", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private Client client;
..
..
..
```

---

```
CriteriaQuery<Client> criteriaQuery =  criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Client.class);
            Root<Client> clientRoot =  criteriaQuery.from(Client.class);
            //Join the Client table with the RoccoRequest table
            final Join<Client, RoccoRequest> clientRoccoJoin = clientRoot.join(Client_.roccoRequest,JoinType.INNER); 

            final Path<String> _requestStatus = clientRoccoJoin.get(RoccoRequest_.statusCode);
            final Path<String> _requestId = clientRoccoJoin.get(RoccoRequest_.requestId);

            final Predicate _crmIdPredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(clientRoot.get(Client_.crmId), CRMId);

            criteriaQuery.multiselect(_requestId,_requestStatus);
            criteriaQuery.where(_crmIdPredicate);

            //Get list of details of existing requests for the client with the request type as ACO
            clientDetails = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();

            if(null != clientDetails) for(Client clientDetail : clientDetails){
                StatusBO statusDetails = new StatusBO();
                    statusDetails.setCode((clientDetail.getRoccoRequest().getStatusCode()));
                PreInitiationBO preinitiateDetails = new PreInitiationBO();
                    preinitiateDetails.getCaseHeader().setRequestId(requestId);
                    preinitiateDetails.setStatus(statusDetails);
                exisitngRequestInfo.add(preinitiateDetails);    
            }
```

I have did some Criteria fetching of the entities. But I'm getting an exception as follows:

> Can not find constructor for "class com.xxx.xxx.model.Client" with
>   argument types "[class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]" to
>   fill data.

Why does JPA expect an argument Constructor? It has anything to do with the association? I tried removing the OneToMany relationship but I still get the error.

Please note that I have added a 2 argument constructor that makes no sense to me. But it works if it's given. log root level has Debug enabled. It has very less information on exception.

Please help.

Comment: and you're performing what operation when you get that? posting the stack trace with any exception would have revealed what you were doing.

Comment: @Neil, Thank you for responding back. The exception stack trace couldn't be printed, though I tried doing it. The application an OSGi bundle and I have debug enabled. I perform a Fetch with join using JPA Criterias for filtering that operates on Client.class which gives the exception.Debug trace on exception below

<openjpa-2.3.0-r422266:1540826 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Failed to execute query "null". Check the query syntax for correctness. See nested exception for details.

Comment: So you perform a QUERY, and you haven't told people what the QUERY was. Good luck with that then ...

Comment: Oops. I couldn't really recollect that I haven't added the operation I was trying to do as I was working on some meetings and late night work. Apologies for it.I just added the Criteria that results in this error. Please find the details. Thank you for the time and pointing out.

Comment: You're creating a query that is supposed to returna List<Client>, but does a multiselect of requestId and requestStatus. That's why JPA tries to construct a Client with two strings as argument. But it doesn't make much sense. That query should not return Clients. Or, if it should return clients, it shouldn't do that multiselect.

Comment: @JBNizet - You are right. The Multi-Select added recently has caused the problem. Thank you for pointing out. Tuples would pave the way for th required result altogether for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As JBNizet pointed out,
I was making a dumb mistake by adding multiselect with two Strings but was having a CrtieriaQuery of type Client.class.

This can either be solved by removing the multiselect(Not in my case) or by Making the CriteriaQuery and other types with Tuples.class instead of Client.class and loop through the Tuples and get as tuple.get(0) etc.

Problem resolved. Thanks @Neil and @JBNizet